# How to make my textbox value change base on value in i selected in combobox

Tags: vb.net

i got text box but not in same form. first textbox is staffid which in login form. second textbox is staff first name which in sale form.

admin staffid's first name is Ng

i insert code below:

```
Private Sub txtId_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtId.TextChanged
Sale.Staff_First_NameTextBox.Text = "select [Staff First Name] from staff where Staffid ='" & txtId.Text.Trim & "'"
```

End Sub
when i insert admin at staffid textbox ,the thing show at Staff_First_NameTextBox is

```
"select [Staff First Name] from staff where Staffid ='admin'"
```

it should be Ng...

anyone can help?

Comment: U select the music id from combobox right? then why u are thinking over Textchanged event of textbox.. u can do it with the help of ComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged Event

Comment: @GoroundoVipa help plsss~T>T

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ComboBox1.Text.Trim.Contains("Moves Like Jagger") = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = "90 Dollars"
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Text.Trim.Contains("Titanium") = True Then
        TextBox1.Text = "120 Dollars"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: if i got many music data then i have key in all?

or got any other easy method to linking them?

Comment: You can use array to shorter your code,for more complex idea i think is better to create a Music registration where you can put the album photo, Singer, Song, price and etc...

Comment: ya i create a table for music already. These music Id and price is one of the data form music table.

what i going to do now is in sale designer i make combo box for music id, textbox for price.
when customer want buy a music(example titanium) then textbox auto show 120 dollar, but i wanted 120 dollar came from database not just simply input....

can teach me how to do it?

Comment: Okay but you better stay attention =D, just joking okay to get the prices to the database first the combox will do the query to get the price into the database like if you choose some song into the combobox the combobox initiate the query command to get the price...

Comment: not very clear,
izzit query code like that?
    select price from dbo.music
    where music id= cbMID.text

cbMID is name of the combo box

Comment: Exactly... try it ,it works like charm, what database are you using ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 Dim Cls as New DatabaseQueries
 Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
     TextBox1.Text.Trim = Cls.getDataInDB("SELECT PRICE FROM tblSongs WHERE SONG = '" & ComboBox1.Text.Trim & "'")
  End Sub

 '===========================Inside the Class DatabaseQueries===================

     Public Function getDataInDB(ByVal sQuery As String) As String
    getDataInDB = Nothing
    Try
        CMD = New SqlCommand(sQuery, TestResult)
        Dim sqlAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
        Dim dataS As DataSet
        sqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(CMD)
        dataS = New DataSet
        sqlAdapter.Fill(dataS, "getRecord")
        getDataInDB = dataS.Tables("getRecord").Rows(0).ItemArray(0).ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

This is the idea =D

Comment: testresult in new SQlCommand is??
what should replace it with?

Comment: may get a last help from you
may show  me what to edit in Class DatabaseQueries to my thing.

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the late response did you get what you want ? or my code is useful to you ?

Comment: Can you edit again and show me a picture to the problem and the code so i can check it precisely... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ohhh okay okay sorry i didn't notice the changes. your problem facing right now is called like form freeze event it means that the form finishes to load so the event occur in other tool will be nothing, but in case of human interaction like licking the button or something.

to overcome the event when loading the form try to insert already the value of the combobox in formLoad so the event will trigger when loading the form like this.

```
  Private Sub Form_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 ComboBox1.Text = "aa"
 End Sub

 Through that the ComboBox will go to its event ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
```

and execute the command on it.

try to put a Break point on the ComboBox event to monitor if the event occur when loading the main Form... Try it =D

Comment: erm......the code like no solve my problem.

my problem facing now is 

i got 5 value(M1-M5) in combo box which linked to music database to get music id.

i select M2, price also show nicely
i select M3, price also show nicely
but when i need select M2 back, it cannot be select, it stack at M3 and price also showing M3's price.

izzit my combo box shuffle or something else?

Comment: Ohhh,,, That's GOOD im happy that you solve it, just ask me if you have a problem =D

Comment: hey bro...i update new question agn~may give me a help?